# How to extract data from online react-table to csv

Tags: excel, csv

I would like to have some way of obtaining the data from NHL.com's stats page which I believe is a react table and has no  tag. An example would be the following:

http://www.nhl.com/stats/team?aggregate=1&reportType=game&dateFrom=2017-10-22&dateTo=2017-12-07&gameType=2&filter=gamesPlayed,gte,1&sort=points,wins

I have tried making an Excel query, but the table doesn't show up in Excel's web browser. I tried just manually copy-pasting from the webpage to Excel/Sheets, but all the data is pasted in the first column.

Any way of getting this information to a csv would be appreciated, *especially* some sort of automated way given a set of filters to pass into the URL.

Comment: If the table doesn’t show up then the data in the table is being called via some JS/Ajax in which Excel browser may have difficulty.. I’d suggest using another language to get that data.